# Bios detects hard drive but it is not seen during installation of Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, laptop, installation

I have an IBM T60 and installed a new hard disk.

This is seen by the operating system, but is not detected during the installation of the Windows XP.

Why is that?

Comment: What OS are you talking about?

Comment: Does the operating system have the needed drivers?

Comment: windows xp professional and i dont think so and if it needs drivers then how would i got about installing thos drivers

Comment: Precisely what XP CD are you using? It from Microsoft? Or is it an IBM recovery disk? What service pack does it have integrated? Most likely, the disk is just too old and not seeing your hard drive is just the first symptom. (You want at least SP2 integrated.)

Answer (score 3):

The drivers for that device can be obtained here: http://support.lenovo.com/en_CY/downloads/default.page?

You'll need to enter the specific model number of your machine, then download any storage related drivers.

You'll then need to put them on a floppy disk, and at the very beginning of the XP install it will ask if you want to install any additional drivers (look at the bottom of the screen while it is still a blue text screen), and hit and F key if so (I think it is F6).

You'll be prompted for a floppy disk, and with that you can install the drivers.

Comment: Yes it IS F6.  Another option in case you don't have a floppy drive is to Slipstream the driver into your Windows Installation Media.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a floppy drive,

Slipstream "Mass storage" drivers into the XP CD.

Driver packs tutorial, read carefully.

http://forum.driverpacks.net/viewtopic.php?id=1449

Download software "Driverpacks Base"

http://driverpacks.net/downloads

You can install other driver packs besides the "Mass Storage", but this will bloat the size of the XP install to DVD size, The only driver packs I suggest to slipstream are

Mass Storage, Chipset, Lan, CPU

This will keep it a size to fit on a CD. If you want all the drivers slipstreamed it will require a DVD burner to make the DVD and a DVD drive on the target installation PC.

I don't change any of the default settings when using the software, just pick the driver packs you want to slipstream and create the ISO image.

If you use other customizing software for other reasons than drivers such as Nlite, use Nlite first then driver packs last or install problems will result. Only use DP to slip drivers, do not use Nlite for this task.

Start with clean unmodified Installation files when using DP for best results.

Note, Driverpacks no longer allows you to download the driverpacks from their site using the program (you will get an error), driverpacks are now distributed via bittorrent, the torrent file for each driverpack can be found on the driverpacks download page, once you have the 7zip Driverpack files you need, copy them (do not unzip them) into the "DriverPacks" folder where you installed the program. When you run the program skip the update driverpacks step if the process.